# QML crashed if static build

Tags: qt, qml, static-linking, remote-desktop, mingw32

I build static `Qt 5.10.1` with mingw32.

Ref: https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/blob/master/windows-build-qt-static/windows-build-qt-static.ps1

For testing purpose, build an empty QML project, it could run perfectly in QtCreator.
But if I copy the release build to another Win10&7 PC which doesn't contain the Qt environment, it will crash after the windows appeared. I'm guessing something missed inside QML.

**Update:**

I found `No qmlscene installed` appears in the `Qt Versions` tab, not sure it relates to the issue or not.

These two files did generate in the build folder.

```
projectname_plugin_import.cpp
projectname_qml_plugin_import.cpp
```

Found the similar issue: https://forum.qt.io/topic/42145/i-can-t-run-static-qt-qml-app-on-another-computer

**Update 2:**

Problem solved but I want to know why.

Here is I tried:

1. Connect a Win PC using remote desktop from another Win PC, run a static build QML program, then it crashed immediately after the Window appeared.
2. Directly login into the same local machine, run the same static build QML program, successful run.
3. Using the remote desktop run dynamic link QML program with Qt libs, successful run.

So the problem is Windows remote desktop, but I can't find the doc or bug report about it, if you have any idea or guessing, please help me.